# How common are adjectives on -ly?

Tags: morphology

How common in English are adjectives ending with -ly? I can remember only "stately" and "unruly". Is it adequate to assume, say in machine text analysis, that apart from several predefined exceptions all adjectives ending with -ly are adverbs? (I'm using a computer word database where adjectives and adverbs are all marked with 'A' and need to distinguish them.)

Comment: There's also "only." Although that can be used as an adjective and an adverb.

Comment: Maybe you could find another word list with better POS. I think moby http://icon.shef.ac.uk/Moby/ has that

Comment: homely, comely, stately, unseemly...

Comment: @Mitch - this can be accepted as answer. thanks! I'm using currently: http://wordlist.aspell.net/alt12dicts-infl-readme/

Comment: @Mitch - I could not open the mobypos.i file with any text editor, seems like it uses some ancient data format. The question is actual.

Comment: What do you mean by 'Is it adequate to assume, say in machine text analysis, that apart from several predefined exceptions all adjectives ending with -ly are adverbs?'? 'Is it adequate to assume, say in machine text analysis, that apart from several predefined exceptions all adjectives ending with -ly are also adverbs?'?

Comment: You can add _-ly_ to many nouns to form adjectives: _brotherly_, _hourly_. If you add _-ly_ to an adjective, it forms an adverb: _happily_, _regularly_.

Comment: @Edwin - well, in the word DB I use: wordlist.aspell.net/alt12dicts-infl-readme there is no distinction between the two: both are marked with 'A'.

Comment: But English certainly distinguishes between the two. If you want to use the words in a non-standard way, that becomes off-topic.

Comment: I cannot for the life of me think of any normal situation where adverbial forms of _-ly_-derived adjectives would see any practical usage—they quite simply tend not to be used as adverbs. That being said, the OED does list quite a few _-ly_ adverbs derived from _-ly_ adjectives: _chillily_, _comelily_, _daylily/dailily_ (!), _earlily_, _friendlily_, _wilily_ (!!), etc. Of the ones mentioned here, _daily_ and _early_ are frequently used as zero-derived adverbs, and I find it hard to believe that any sane person would say things like, “She smiled comelily/friendlily at him”.

Comment: ... The day lily flowers ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to distinguish most of them is by looking at the base word when *-ly* is removed.

If the base word is a noun, then the word is an adjective, usually meaning something that has the qualities of the noun (but when the noun is a unit of time, it means recurring at that interval).

If the base word is an adjective, then the word is an adverb.

Note that adding the *-ly* suffix sometimes requires changing the spelling, so the base word may not be obvious. For instance, the adjective *happy* produces the adverb *happily*.

However, as with most of natural language, these rules are not absolute, and there are some exceptions. Some words can be used as both adjectives and adverbs. And in some cases, over time the original root word has changed form.

There are also some irregular entries, like *comely* (some may have originally fit the above formations, but the base words are no longer in use).

You'll need to have special cases for the exceptions, which you can find at word lists.

Comment: _leisure_ is a noun, _leisurely_ is an adjective: _We took a leisurely walk_

Comment: _deadly_ is both an adjective and adverb, although the adjective is more common. It seems like it comes from the meaning of _causing death_, so the ultimate root is really the noun _death_, but that has been lost in history.

Comment: I've added caveats to my answer.

Comment: There really are hundreds of these. Some like *only* and *wiley* aren’t so strange given *one-ly* and *wiles*. But there are plenty of “exceptions”.  *Early* birds were never once earls in an earlier age. *Holy* relics need not be perforated. *Silly* thoughts are not confined to window ledges. *Ugly* paintings are rarely ogled. *Lonely* hearts, *lively* company, *lowly* ambitions, *measly* portions, and *portly* barkeeps are all something else — as too are *wobbly* chairs and *niggly* nuisances which come from verbs. And *jelly* beans is probably today best thought of as a noun–noun compound.

Answer (score 0):

*[Elderly](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/elderly)* ( adjective ) is another such word:

> adjective
>
> (Of a person) old or aging:
>   *an elderly relative*

Comment: Welcome to ELU, Abdul. Your answer could be improved by citing authoritative resource material.